# Laravel Echo - default.a.channel is not a function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-echo

I'm trying to setup Laravel Echo with pusher, to implement real time notifications.

First, i have installed Laravel Echo and Pusher:

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

After this, in  `bootstrap.js`  i have uncomment the code (as guide say):

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'my_key',
    encrypted: true
});
Echo.channel('orders')
    .listen('TestEvent', (e) => {
        console.log('pippo');
    });
```

I have run `gulp` and now when i visit the page, i get this error:

```
bootstrap.js?5e63:50 Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_laravel_echo___default.a.channel is not a function
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Changing `Echo.channel('orders')` to `window.Echo.channel('orders')` should fix that.

Comment: Very niceeeeeeeeeeee!

Comment: Still helping in 2021! Thank you for this!